# visual studio open link seperate form

Tags: c#

Basically trying to learn a few things I havn't tried yet. I want to make a small program that has a Textbox and Button.

Whats typed into the textbox field will be added to the end of a url applied from the button.
http://website.com/stuff?things= +textboxValue

After you click the launch button, I want the url created with the entered text, to open in a second form.

I have everything working except for the text from form1 to carry over to form2. Just wondering how I can go about this.

**Form 1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.LinkTarget = textBox1.Text;
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 newFrm = new Form3();
            newFrm.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string LinkTarget {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string myUrl = "http://website.com/stuff?things=" + LinkTarget;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of what I am going for.
Form one has text box and button.
when you click the button it will open http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ in the second form. the second form is basically a browser. 
but, in form one if I type 41090977 before I hit the button, it will open http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/41090977

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a number of ways to pass information between form instances in C#.  You can supply a value on the constructor, set it to a property, pass it to a method call, make it static, store it in some commonly accessible location, etc.  Supplying a value to a class for it to use is pretty broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property in form2, which you set before you open it:

```
//... other form2 code

public string LinkTarget {
    get;
    set;
}
```

You can set the value like this (in `button1_Click`):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.LinkTarget = myTextBox.Text;
form2.Show();
```

Within form2 you can use the value of the property to create your link. In your current code you have just defined the property. You have to use its content to create your link. This is done by attaching the property value to your string containing the URL with the `+` operator:

```
string myUrl = "http://website.com/stuff?things=" + LinkTarget;
```

Comment: So i have set in the property window of my Form2 to open the link, so now when I click the button on form one it opens the link, but still not linking to textbox from form1.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted, anything go here

Comment: @JakeJigsaw: Please clarify what you mean with "linking to textbox". You best updated your question to specify exactly what you wont. If you want to pass the value of your text box to form2 when you open it, the way I described is what you have to do. If you want to do something different or more complex, say so in your question.

Comment: im trying to do it they way you have specified. I just havnt got it to work. I just want the text that is typed into the text box on form1 to be added to the end of the url on form2's WebBrowser

Comment: @JakeJigsaw: What have you done as for _"Within form2 you can use the value of the property to create your link"_? Do you do anything with the value of your property? When the property is set, the link is not updated. You have to do that before you show the form. Either do that in the property setter, create a method or use your FormShow event.

Comment: The only errors I have now, are "An object referenced is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Show() ... and 'form2.LinkTarget .. ive tried naming it to Form2 as well. @Sefe

Comment: @JakeJigsaw: Please add your current code to your question. I can't _guess_ what's wrong.

Comment: @JakeJigsaw: Please update **your question** with the code. Regardless of that, you have to actually create an instance of your `Form2`. Like you do this in linkLabel1_LinkClicked.

Comment: do I need to add anything to textBox1_TextChanged?

Comment: @JakeJigsaw: It's not a good a idea to program by guesswork. Don't write any line without understanding what you're doing. The  solution is in my answer, but unless you go at least through some effort yourself, nobody can help you. For learning programming there are better places to go than SO.